# Flashing new rom, are old files deleted or hidden?

Tags: rom-flashing, sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery, partitions

I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or it's something normal.

I had CM9 on my Galaxy s3 and decided to try another rom (Paranoid). I didn't like the new one I installed and downloaded another (Carbon). But I am noticing that my internal storage is close to being full now. But when I browse the phone from my PC, I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary.

I copied Carbon zip onto the phone, but clockwork mod is not even seeing it, I am noticing a lot of files from the sd and I'm still seeing the Paranoid zip from clockwork mod, but I cannot see it from my PC.

Did I skip a step somewhere? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens to existing files when flashing a new ROM very much depends of the location in question:

- your SDCard (internal or external) is not touched at all, apart from the fact you're placing the `update.zip` for flashing there.
- your internal storage (`/data` and `/cache`) is neither touched by the flashing process itself. But when switching between different ROMs, it's recommended to wipe these two to avoid complications
- some other locations are usually wiped and rewritten. This includes for sure `/system`, and in most cases also `/boot`

I know of no case where files are "hidden". Either the entire partition is not touched at all, or it is wiped. It *might* be that on some partitions files are simply overwritten, though I've never heard of such a case either.

Comment: hi Izzy, I think we talked a while ago, I digged deeper and released I needed to format my sd card, all the other roms where still there, but not showing when browsing through the pc.

Comment: I remember something like that. But where is "there"? External SD? Then you could simply put it into a card reader to check. But if I remember correctly, your issue was that it was not on "removable memory". Which leaves `adb shell` to look inside. I use a combo of [adb rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) and [adbd Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) for such things, but that requires a Linux PC :)

Comment: There meaning the internal sd, I still didn't see the files, but when I carried out with the format, i freed up about 10gb or so.

Comment: Well, that's another possibility -- but only works if you don't need to retain *any* of the data there, as it would "blank" the entire "drive".